# Emacs: Automatically show files in directory with find-file

Tags: emacs

When navigating through a deep directory tree with `find-file` (C-x C-f), I often find myself 1) tapping the Tab key to autocomplete a directory name, and 2) immediately tapping the Tab key again to see the contents of that directory. I do this so routinely that I'd love it if I didn't have to hit Tab a second time to see those contents.

Is there a way to automatically display the contents of a directory after autocompleting its name?

Also, I've played around with ido-mode and helm, but I wasn't a huge fan of either, so I ended up switching back to the default `find-file`.

Comment: On OSX, I am able to navigate the dired-mode directories just about as efficiently as the native Finder.app -- no need for ido or tabbing -- just isearch-ing when the directories have lots of folders and/or files.  I now find all my files with dired-mode.

Comment: @lawlist: If he is tapping `TAB` again as soon as he gets to a directory then he is clearly not opening directories with `C-x C-f`.  IOW, he is not using Dired much, if at all.  (I like Dired, but it doesn't sound like he does.) I would also think that `TAB TAB` would be pretty quick, but I guess it's not quick enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hesitate to say this, as I doubt you will find it satisfactory wrt what you are looking for, but in case it helps:

You can configure [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) so that it immediately shows all candidates and updates the matches as you type.  See [Icicles Incremental Completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Icompletion).

The relevant options are [`icicle-show-Completions-initially-flag`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Customization_and_General_Tips#icicle-show-Completions-initially-flag) and [`icicle-incremental-completion`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Customization_and_General_Tips#icicle-incremental-completion) (and maybe [`icicle-find-file-expand-directory-flag`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Customization_and_General_Tips#icicle-find-file-expand-directory-flag)).

(There are also options [`icicle-incremental-completion-delay`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Customization_and_General_Tips#icicle-incremental-completion-delay) and [`icicle-incremental-completion-threshold`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Customization_and_General_Tips#icicle-incremental-completion-threshold).)

Comment: I honestly haven't looked much into Icicles since, well, there's so much to look through, but those links were very very helpful. Thank you Drew!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like `ido-mode` or `helm`, you might find `icomplete-mode` more to your liking: it doesn't overwrite as many keybindings as `ido` does.